# Setting multiple porerties using paramters- neo4j cypher

Tags: javascript, neo4j, cypher

I want to set the name and desripion of an object using parameters. I tried a statement but it doesn't work.

```
             MATCH(user: User{ID: $userId})<-[:CREATED_BY]-(cart: Cart {ID: $cartId})
             SET cart.name = $name, cart.description = $description
             RETURN cart
```

all the variables are properly initialized. THis statement works if I use the values directly instead of using parameters. but doesn't work when i use paramters.

Comment: It is not clear how your statement does “not work”. Does it return cart or nothing at all? Probably something is wrong in the way you pass the parameters .

Comment: Indeed, can you share the code that sets these parameters?

Comment: I guess you are doing this in the neo4j desktop browser?  and using the appropriate syntax?  :param name ⇒ 'Joe'    [Reference](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/syntax/parameters/)
if not in the browser we will need more context

Answer (score 0):

Update: The issue was not with the Query statement. An await keyword was missing in the API associated with it. Thank you for all your responses.